# C# sms library long messages

Tags: c#, gsm

I am using sms library is my project,

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20420/How-To-Send-and-Receive-SMS-using-GSM-Modem
```

Following is the link where from i am picking the references. I have a problem that if a message exceed from one message length then it give me error.

My Question is : How can i send long message with this library.

Following is my code

```
SmsSubmitPdu pdu = new SmsSubmitPdu("Long Message","Number", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should follow below points for sending long sms :

> 1.Add User Data Header
>
> 2.Add Padding bit to encode your message.

These links will surely help you :

http://hiteshagja.com/send-long-sms/

http://mobiletidings.com/2009/02/18/combining-sms-messages/

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have learned alot through that, +ve for you (Sorry i am new so i am not permitted for reputation). Still I am wondering how to use the scenario is smspdu.